# Print lottery number out

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to print out lottery number from 00000 to 99999 where each number has a serial number 0..5.

I've tried to use the combination function in ruby, but it wont use the same numbers for a combination

I've tried to use a while loop.

```
count = 0
while count <= 99999

puts "number = " + count.to_s
count +=1
end
```

This will print number 0-99999.

My problem is to make 0 5 digits and giving each number a serial number.

Answer (score 2):

```
(0..99999).each { |count| puts "Number = #{count.to_s.rjust(5, '0')}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

To print an integer with always 5 characters :

```
sprintf '%05d­', count
```

Comment: `sprintf` "prints" to a string. The OP wants to print to console so use `printf` or `puts '%05d' % [count]`. Ruby's String class has the `%` ("format") method which takes a standard "printf" format string.